# Testing Extjs controller with Jasmine returns TypeError

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, extjs, jasmine, phantomjs

We have set up a unit testing environment.

PhantomJS will provide a headless browser to simulate the tests and the tests will be written in Jasmine framework.

For simple examples (testing simple JS code) everything works fine. We have problems figuring out how should the Jasmine code for running a test for a Sencha ExtJS 4.2 controller look like.

For example we have set up a simple Sencha project that inserts an item into the store on a button click.

```
Ext.define('TestApp.controller.TestController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [
        {
            ref: 'myButton',
            selector: '#mybutton'
        }
    ],

    onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        var user = {
            "Name": makeString(),
            "Surname": makeString()
        };

        console.debug(user);

        var store = Ext.getStore("User");
        store.add(user);
    },

    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "#mybutton": {
                click: this.onButtonClick
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Below is the test code in Jasmine that should test if a button was clicked.

```
describe("Main Controller", function () {

    var controller;

    beforeEach(function () {
        controller = Ext.create('TestApp.controller.TestController', {
            application: TestApp.app
        });
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        controller = null;
    });

    describe("Controls", function () {
        it("Controller is loaded", function() {
        expect(controller != null).toBeTruthy();
    });

        it("button clicked", function () {
            var generateButton = controller.getMyButton();

        //Start listening to the component
            controller.init();

        generateButton.fireEvent('click')
            expect(controller.onButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

But the code gives an error in the second test:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'generateButton.fireEvent') in file:///home/anar/SenchaArchitect3/TestProject/UnitTests/TestControllerSpec.js (line 76)
```

What exactly are we doing wrong and is our approach the right one?

Comment: I test my apps (sencha touch and ExtJS) with siesta. You can take a look. http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/

Comment: Just out of the blue - is the makeString() function defined anywhere? Also, place a `debugger` statement inside the failing test, run it again and step through the code. That will help you to find the problem. And yes, the approach is the right one.